# Embed API Third Party Visualizations

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to run this script https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/

The problem is that when I enter the browser console gives me this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

so I thought enough to add

```
<div id="view-name"></div>
```

in the code and in fact part of the script, but with a horrible graphics.

That does not fully reflect the real one.

The script is used in this way:

```
{literal}
<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>
{/literal}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/components/view-selector2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/components/date-range-selector.js"></script>
<script src="https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/components/active-users.js"></script>
                <header class="boxHeadline">
                    <h1>Benvenuto nel pannello di amministrazione</h1>
                </header>
                <article>
                    <div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
                    <div id="view-selector-container"></div>
                    <div id="active-users-container"></div>
                    <div id="view-name"></div>
                    <div id="chart-1-container"></div>
                    <div id="legend-1-container"></div>
                    <div id="chart-2-container"></div>
                    <div id="legend-2-container"></div>
                    <div id="chart-3-container"></div>
                    <div id="legend-3-container"></div>
                    <div id="chart-4-container"></div>
                    <div id="legend-4-container"></div>
                </article>
                {literal}
                <script>
                    // == NOTE ==
                    // This code uses ES6 promises. If you want to use this code in a browser
                    // that doesn't supporting promises natively, you'll have to include a polyfill.

                    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

                      /**
                       * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
                       * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
                       * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
                       */
                      gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
                        container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
                        clientid: 'xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
                      });


                      /**
                       * Create a new ActiveUsers instance to be rendered inside of an
                       * element with the id "active-users-container" and poll for changes every
                       * five seconds.
                       */
                      var activeUsers = new gapi.analytics.ext.ActiveUsers({
                        container: 'active-users-container',
                        pollingInterval: 5
                      });


                      /**
                       * Add CSS animation to visually show the when users come and go.
                       */
                      activeUsers.once('success', function() {
                        var element = this.container.firstChild;
                        var timeout;

                        this.on('change', function(data) {
                          var element = this.container.firstChild;
                          var animationClass = data.delta > 0 ? 'is-increasing' : 'is-decreasing';
                          element.className += (' ' + animationClass);

                          clearTimeout(timeout);
                          timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            element.className =
                                element.className.replace(/ is-(increasing|decreasing)/g, '');
                          }, 3000);
                        });
                      });


                      /**
                       * Create a new ViewSelector2 instance to be rendered inside of an
                       * element with the id "view-selector-container".
                       */
                      var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2({
                        container: 'view-selector-container',
                      })
                      .execute();


                      /**
                       * Update the activeUsers component, the Chartjs charts, and the dashboard
                       * title whenever the user changes the view.
                       */
                      viewSelector.on('viewChange', function(data) {
                        var title = document.getElementById('view-name');
                        title.innerHTML = data.property.name + ' (' + data.view.name + ')';

                        // Start tracking active users for this view.
                        activeUsers.set(data).execute();

                        // Render all the of charts for this view.
                        renderWeekOverWeekChart(data.ids);
                        renderYearOverYearChart(data.ids);
                        renderTopBrowsersChart(data.ids);
                        renderTopCountriesChart(data.ids);
                      });


                      /**
                       * Draw the a chart.js line chart with data from the specified view that
                       * overlays session data for the current week over session data for the
                       * previous week.
                       */
                      function renderWeekOverWeekChart(ids) {

                        // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
                        var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

                        var thisWeek = query({
                          'ids': ids,
                          'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
                          'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
                          'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                          'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                        });

                        var lastWeek = query({
                          'ids': ids,
                          'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
                          'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
                          'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).subtract(1, 'week')
                              .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                          'end-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(6).subtract(1, 'week')
                              .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                        });

                        Promise.all([thisWeek, lastWeek]).then(function(results) {

                          var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
                          var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
                          var labels = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[0]; });

                          labels = labels.map(function(label) {
                            return moment(label, 'YYYYMMDD').format('ddd');
                          });

                          var data = {
                            labels : labels,
                            datasets : [
                              {
                                label: 'Last Week',
                                fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
                                strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                                pointColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                                pointStrokeColor : '#fff',
                                data : data2
                              },
                              {
                                label: 'This Week',
                                fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
                                strokeColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
                                pointColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
                                pointStrokeColor : '#fff',
                                data : data1
                              }
                            ]
                          };

                          new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-1-container')).Line(data);
                          generateLegend('legend-1-container', data.datasets);
                        });
                      }


                      /**
                       * Draw the a chart.js bar chart with data from the specified view that
                       * overlays session data for the current year over session data for the
                       * previous year, grouped by month.
                       */
                      function renderYearOverYearChart(ids) {

                        // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
                        var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

                        var thisYear = query({
                          'ids': ids,
                          'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
                          'metrics': 'ga:users',
                          'start-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                          'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                        });

                        var lastYear = query({
                          'ids': ids,
                          'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
                          'metrics': 'ga:users',
                          'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'year').date(1).month(0)
                              .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                          'end-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).subtract(1, 'day')
                              .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                        });

                        Promise.all([thisYear, lastYear]).then(function(results) {
                          var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
                          var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
                          var labels = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                                        'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

                          // Ensure the data arrays are at least as long as the labels array.
                          // Chart.js bar charts don't (yet) accept sparse datasets.
                          for (var i = 0, len = labels.length; i < len; i++) {
                            if (data1[i] === undefined) data1[i] = null;
                            if (data2[i] === undefined) data2[i] = null;
                          }

                          var data = {
                            labels : labels,
                            datasets : [
                              {
                                label: 'Last Year',
                                fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
                                strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                                data : data2
                              },
                              {
                                label: 'This Year',
                                fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
                                strokeColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
                                data : data1
                              }
                            ]
                          };

                          new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-2-container')).Bar(data);
                          generateLegend('legend-2-container', data.datasets);
                        })
                        .catch(function(err) {
                          console.error(err.stack);
                        });
                      }


                      /**
                       * Draw the a chart.js doughnut chart with data from the specified view that
                       * show the top 5 browsers over the past seven days.
                       */
                      function renderTopBrowsersChart(ids) {

                        query({
                          'ids': ids,
                          'dimensions': 'ga:browser',
                          'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
                          'sort': '-ga:pageviews',
                          'max-results': 5
                        })
                        .then(function(response) {

                          var data = [];
                          var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

                          response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
                            data.push({ value: +row[1], color: colors[i], label: row[0] });
                          });

                          new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-3-container')).Doughnut(data);
                          generateLegend('legend-3-container', data);
                        });
                      }


                      /**
                       * Draw the a chart.js doughnut chart with data from the specified view that
                       * compares sessions from mobile, desktop, and tablet over the past seven
                       * days.
                       */
                      function renderTopCountriesChart(ids) {
                        query({
                          'ids': ids,
                          'dimensions': 'ga:country',
                          'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
                          'sort': '-ga:sessions',
                          'max-results': 5
                        })
                        .then(function(response) {

                          var data = [];
                          var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

                          response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
                            data.push({
                              label: row[0],
                              value: +row[1],
                              color: colors[i]
                            });
                          });

                          new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-4-container')).Doughnut(data);
                          generateLegend('legend-4-container', data);
                        });
                      }


                      /**
                       * Extend the Embed APIs `gapi.analytics.report.Data` component to
                       * return a promise the is fulfilled with the value returned by the API.
                       * @param {Object} params The request parameters.
                       * @return {Promise} A promise.
                       */
                      function query(params) {
                        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                          var data = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({query: params});
                          data.once('success', function(response) { resolve(response); })
                              .once('error', function(response) { reject(response); })
                              .execute();
                        });
                      }


                      /**
                       * Create a new canvas inside the specified element. Set it to be the width
                       * and height of its container.
                       * @param {string} id The id attribute of the element to host the canvas.
                       * @return {RenderingContext} The 2D canvas context.
                       */
                      function makeCanvas(id) {
                        var container = document.getElementById(id);
                        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                        container.innerHTML = '';
                        canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
                        canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;
                        container.appendChild(canvas);

                        return ctx;
                      }


                      /**
                       * Create a visual legend inside the specified element based off of a
                       * Chart.js dataset.
                       * @param {string} id The id attribute of the element to host the legend.
                       * @param {Array.<Object>} items A list of labels and colors for the legend.
                       */
                      function generateLegend(id, items) {
                        var legend = document.getElementById(id);
                        legend.innerHTML = items.map(function(item) {
                          var color = item.color || item.fillColor;
                          var label = item.label;
                          return '<li><i style="background:' + color + '"></i>' + label + '</li>';
                        }).join('');
                      }


                      // Set some global Chart.js defaults.
                      Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 60;
                      Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = 'easeInOutQuart';
                      Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
                      Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;

                    });
                </script>
                {/literal}
            </div>
        </section>
```

Below the article tag is the rest of the javascript code.

How can I resolve to see perfectly the embed?

Thank you for your answers.

P.S. [Embed API Third party visualization > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null (cb=gapi.loaded_0:139)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638488/embed-api-third-party-visualization-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-i) How could I understand I They try to follow this question. But unfortunately I had that result. It is as if he were reading the javascript code.

Comment: It appears that the issue is because of a lack of CSS on the containing chart divs. My fix? Add a `style="max-width: 400px; height: 250px;"` to the charts, and style the rest.