# Google's Embed API Third Party Visualizations fails to display graphics

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

**Google's Embed API Third Party Visualizations fails to display graphics.**

My page at issue:

```
http://www.yoursitename.us/tpv.html
```

I download the components (Git) to my server, I believe correctly placed in `/public/javascript/embed-api/components`.

Logged in to Google Chrome as the owner of the Analytics Account.
Navigating to https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/ the page displays my Google analytics data correctly.

I follow instructions on the page and embed the code into simple html pages:

```
-Basic Dashboard (basic.html)
-Multipleviews (mv.html)and
-Interactive Charts (ic.html)
-Custom Components (cc.html)
 and
-Third Party Visualizations (tpv.html)
```

All display as expected (in need of CSS) however, the Third Party Visualizations authenticates and then displays, "You are logged in as: "  and the selectors display correctly and function correctly but the graphics do not display.

The Chrome developer's console shows an error, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null".

Image of error is at http://www.yoursitename.us/images-errors/github-error-tpv.png.
The second and third error in the first section above are a result of me changing the selectors on the page.

I tried moving the  tag around to make sure the elements were all loaded on the page and it makes no difference and the errors are the same.

The offending code seems to be:

```
/**
* Update the activeUsers component, the Chartjs charts, and the dashboard
* title whenever the user changes the view.
*/
viewSelector.on('viewChange', function(data) {
var title = document.getElementById('view-name');
title.innerHTML = data.property.name + ' (' + data.view.name + ')';
```

A previous question addresses this issue: 
[Embed API Third party visualization > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null (cb=gapi.loaded_0:139)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638488/embed-api-third-party-visualization-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-i)

Resolution reported as:

> *"I just added an element with 'view-name' as the ID ..."*

The question is repeated here with a similar solution: [Embed API Third Party Visualizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31504144/3606147)

I add:

```
<div> id="view-name"></div>
```

above the other containers(DIVs) in the demo HTML.

The new page:

```
http://www.yoursitename.us/tpv-mod.html
```

Now the line graph and the bar chart display after a fashion,  but the doughnut graphs fail with the error in he Chrome developer's console:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null". (see above image)
```

This is what the page looks like:

```
http://www.yoursitename.us/images-errors/github-error-tpv.png.
```

Several hours later, I refresh the page and no errors show in the Chrome developer console. (Curious, but perhaps not central to the issue.)

Why will the page not display the doughnut graphics?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd appreciate feedback on the qualitative aspect of this question, i.e. clarity, following this site's suggestions for asking a good question, etc. Thanks

Comment: The actual url is: http://www.yoursitename.us/tpv.html   Thank you.